# android gradle -- compile two pure java projects to dex

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, dex

I have two pure java projects (:java:libs:proj1, :java:libs:proj2) that produce two classes.jars when they are built.  The two jars "combined" include the exact classes that I would like to convert into dex jar i.e. a JAR file with classes.dex in it.

Can someone help me with converting the two pure java projects into a single JAR with classes.dex in it?

Here is what I tried doing.

1) Create a separate Android Library project (apply plugin: 'android-library') and include the two java projects as dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':java:libs:proj1')
    compile project(':java:libs:proj2')
}
```

However, with this approach, it doesn't generate a dex file.  Instead, it produces an ".aar" file which contains only the .class files of the two projects.  If I can convert this .aar file to its dex, then this would be perfect but apparently the "android-library" plugin does not have a "dex" task.

2) Create an Android project (apply plugin: 'android') and include the two projects as depenendencies. (Similar to above but using 'android' instead of 'android-library').

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':java:libs:proj1')
    compile project(':java:libs:proj2')
}
```

This approach does create the dex files that I need, however it also includes ALL the dependencies for my two pure java projects.  So for example, my java projects depend on JUnit, BouncyCastle and some other external JAva projects.  Inside of the classes.dex, I see that it has included *everything*.  Is there a way to tell the "dex" task to not include dependencies "transitively"?

I only want the classes directly associated with my two java projects into dex.  I wish there was an easy way :(

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

will modify compile in dependencies to provided help? please also check [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

25.4.7. Excluding transitive dependencies
You can exclude a transitive dependency either by configuration or by dependency:

Example 25.14. Excluding transitive dependencies